# Clojure: Testing every value from map operation for truth

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, dictionary

How can I test that every value in the collection returned by `map` is true?

I am using the following:

```
(defn test [f coll]
  (every? #(identity %) (map f coll)))
```

with the anonymous function `#(identity %)`, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

I cannot use `(apply and ...)` because `and` is a macro.

**UPDATE**: BTW, I am making my way through *The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths, and Programming*, by Kees Doets and Jan can Eijck, but doing the exercises in Clojure. It's a very interesting book.

Comment: The way you type "true" in a typewriter font makes it look like you want to check for the exact value Boolean/TRUE, but your code accepts any values that are not nil or false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
(every? true? coll)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any single function that does that (`(g (map f coll))`)? I looked through the docs, but could not find one.

Comment: Note that true? tests for boolean true, not logical true. For logical true, you would use identity.  I believe there was some talk of adding a single-arg arity to every? which would be the equivalent of (every? identity coll), thus would be that single function you want.

Answer (score 5):

either

```
(every? identity (map f coll))
```

or

```
(every? f coll)
```